# convert the first 10 items in a list to an image, then convert subsequent groups on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, anchor

I'm converting anchors to images, fading them into the page in order, then removing the anchor (and parent `li`) from the page.

I'd like to load in the first 10 items from the list, then loads in additional groups of 10 by clicking a load-more button. Not really sure what the best way to do this is.

Markup is below, everything works appropriately.

HTML:

```
<section class="userGallery headers">
  <ul>    
    <li>
      <a href="path/to/image.jpg" title="image_name"></a>
    </li>    
    <li>
      <a href="path/to/image.jpg" title="image_name"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

into:

```
<section class="userGallery headers">
  <ul>    
  </ul>
  <img class="user" src"path/to/image.jpg" alt="image_name" />
  <img class="user" src"path/to/image.jpg" alt="image_name" />
</section>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function(){

// User Uploads

    $('.userGallery li').each(function(){
        var loc = $(this).find('a').attr('href'),
            img = $('.userGallery').append($('<img/>', { class: 'user', src: loc }));

        $(this).remove();

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.user').animate({ opacity:1 },400);
        }, 100);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

is something like this what you want?

```
<a href="#" id="load10more">load 10 more</a>

$("#load10more").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
   for(i=0;i<10;i++)
   {
     $("ul").append.('<li><a href="path/to/image_' + i + '.jpg" title="image_name"></a></li>');
   }
});
```

Comment: kind of sort of, now that I think about it, I need to rephrase the question. First, I need to figure out how to take a list and convert only the first ten items, then add additional groups of 10 when clicking the load more button

Comment: Maybe use multiple <ul> elements and only ever add 10 to each <ul> and give each an id like:

<ul id="my-gallery-1">
</ul>

so you can differentiate between them and target them individually.

Comment: i dont have control of the outputted markup. besides, that's extra bits that don't need to be there. i need to make an array and do some stuff and things